# GitHub Branches: Case-Sensitivity Issue?

Tags: windows, git, github, branch, case-sensitive

I seem to be having an issue with a repository continually recreating branches locally because of some branches on remote. I'm on a Windows machine, so I suspect that it's a case sensitivity issue.

Here's an example couple commands:

```
$ git pull
From https://github.com/{my-repo}
 * [new branch]          Abc -> origin/Abc
 * [new branch]          Def -> origin/Def
Already up to date.

$ git pull -p
From https://github.com/{my-repo}
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/abc
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/def
 * [new branch]          Abc -> origin/Abc
 * [new branch]          Def -> origin/Def
Already up to date.
```

When doing a `git pull`, the branches in question are capitalized. When I do a `git pull -p` (for pruning), it first tries to delete lowercased versions of the branches, then create capitalized versions.

The remote branches are capitalized (`origin/Abc` and `origin/Def`).

I have tried to temporarily change my Git config such that `ignorecase=false` (it is currently `ignorecase=true`). But I noticed no change in behavior. I'm guessing there's something local on my end that's currently holding onto those lowercased branches. But `git branch` does not show any version of these branches locally.

Short of completely obliterating the repository (a fresh `git clone` in a separate folder does not pull these phantom branches when trying pulls/fetches), is there anything I can do?

Comment: Did you check that `ignorecase` is not defined at multiple levels (which is not a problem in itself but could cause you to unadvertantly fiddle with an overridden config parameter while the strongest level stays unchanged)? I think about `local`, `global` and `system` mostly.

Comment: @RomainValeri when I did `git config core.ignorecase` it always reported the expected value. There aren't any `.git` subfolders or global settings overriding from what I can tell.

Comment: What is the content of `./.git/refs/heads/`?

Comment: @nowox other branches, but not `abc` or `def` ones.

Comment: @Scott, what about the content of your `.git/config` do you have mention of both `Abc` and `abc`?

Comment: @nowox no mention there either, but it was in remotes. See my answer (solved).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Git, branches are just pointers to a commit. The branches are stores as plain files on your `.git` repository.

For instance you may have `abc` and `def` files on `.git/refs/heads`.

```
$ tree .git/refs/heads/
.git/refs/heads/
├── abc
├── def
└── master
```

The content of these files is just the commit number on which the branch is pointing.

I am not sure, but I think the option `ignorecase` is only relevant to your working directory, not the `.git` folder. So to remove the *weird* capitalized branches, you may just need to remove/rename the files in `.git/refs/heads`.

In addition to this, the upstream link from a local branch to a remote branch is stored on the `.git/config` file. In this file you may have something like:

```
[branch "Abc"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/abc
```

Notice in this example that the remote branch is named `Abc` but the local branch is `abc` (lowercase).

To solve your issue I would try to:

1. Modify the `.git/config` file
2. Rename the corrupted branches in `.git/refs/heads` such as `abc` is renamed `abc-old`
3. Try your `git pull`

Comment: This led me to the solution. I post an answer but the tl;dr version is `.git/refs/remotes/origin` had `abc/old` while remote kept wanting `Abc/new`. I deleted `.git/refs/remotes/origin/abc` and now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 35):

Git is schizophrenic about this.<sup>1</sup>  Parts of Git *are* case-sensitive, so that branch `HELLO` and branch `hello` are *different* branches.  Other parts of Git are, on Windows and MacOS anyway, case-*in*sensitive, so that branch `HELLO` and branch `hello` are *the same* branch.

The result is confusion.  The situation is best simply avoided entirely.

To correct the problem:

1. Set some *additional*, private and temporary, branch or tag name(s) that you won't find confusing, to remember any commit hash IDs you really care about, in your own local repository.  Then run `git pack-refs --all` so that all your references are packed.  This removes all the *file names*, putting all your references into the `.git/packed-refs` flat-file, where their names are case-sensitive.  Your Git can now tell your `Abc` from your `abc`, if you have both.

   Now that your repository is de-confused, *delete* any bad branch names.  Your temporary names hold the values you want to remember.  You can delete both `abc` *and* `Abc` if one or both might be messed up.  Your `remember-abc` has the *correct* hash in it.
2. Go to the Linux server machine that has the branches that differ only in case from yours.  (It's always a Linux machine; this problem never occurs on Windows or MacOS servers because they do the case-folding early enough that you never *create* the problem in the first place.)  There, rename or delete the offending bad names.

   The Linux machine has no issues with case—branches whose name differs only in case are always different—so there is no weirdness here.  It may take a few steps, and a few `git branch` commands to list all the names, but eventually, you'll have nothing but clear and distinct names: there will be no branches named `Abc` and `abc` both.

   If there are no such problems on the Linux server, step 2 is "do nothing".
3. Use `git fetch --prune` on your local system.  You now no longer have any bad names as remote-tracking names, because in step 2, you made sure that the server—the system your local Git calls `origin`—has no bad names, and your local Git has made your local `origin/*` names match their branch names.
4. Now re-create any branch names you want locally, and/or rename the temporary names you made in step 1.  For instance if you made `remember-abc` to remember `abc`, you can just run `git branch -m remember-abc abc` to *move* `remember-abc` to `abc`.

   If `abc` should have `origin/abc` set as its upstream, do that now:

   ```
   git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/abc abc
   ```

   (You can do this in step 1 when you create `remember-abc`, but I think it makes more sense here so I put it in step 4.)

There are various shortcuts you can use, instead of the 4 steps above.  I listed all four this way for clarity of purpose: it should be obvious to you what each step is *intended to accomplish* and, if you read the rest of this, *why* you are doing that step.

The reason the problem occurs is outlined in [nowox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55052709/1256452): Git sometimes store the branch name in a file name, and sometimes stores it as a string in a data file.  Since Windows (and MacOS) tends to use file-name-conflation, the file-name variant retains its original case, but ignores attempts to create a second file of the other case-variant name, and then Git thinks that `Abc` and `abc` are otherwise *the same*.  The data-in-a-file variant retains the case-distinction as well as the value-distinction and believes that `Abc` and `abc` are two different branches that identify two different commits.

When `git rev-parse refs/heads/abc` or `git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/abc` gets its information from `.git/packed-refs`—a data file containing strings—it gets the "right" information.  But when it gets its information from the file system, an attempt to open `.git/refs/heads/abc` or `.git/refs/remotes/origin/abc` actually opens `.git/refs/heads/Abc` (if that file exists right now) or the similarly-named remote-tracking variant (if that file exists), and Git gets the "wrong" information.

Setting `core.ignorecase` (to anything) does not help at all as this affects *only* the way that Git deals with case-folding in the *work-tree*.  Files inside Git's internal databases are not affected in any way.

This whole problem would never come up if, e.g., Git used a real database to store its <reference-name, hash-ID> table.  Using individual files works fine on Linux.  It does not work fine on Windows and MacOS, not this way anyway.  Using individual files *could* work there *if* Git didn't store them in files with readable names—for instance, instead of `refs/heads/master`, perhaps Git could use a file named `refs/heads/6d6173746572`, though that halves the available component-name length.  (Exercise: how is 0x6d `m`, 0x61 `a`, and so on?)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, this is the wrong word.  It's sure descriptive though.  A better word might be *schizoid*, as used in the title of [one episode of The Prisoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Schizoid_Man_(The_Prisoner)), but it too has the wrong meaning.  The root word here is really [*schism*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/schism), meaning split and somewhat self-opposed, and that's what we're driving at here.

Comment: Very informative response! `.git/refs/remotes/origin` had the casing for `abc` and `def` saved (apparently some old, no-longer-existing feature branches used the lowercase version, so the folders were still there).

Comment: It isn't Git's fault. Git relies to the `filesystem`. As a branch is just the name of a file, if the `filesystem` isn't case sensitive, git would be unable to distinguish between the case of two branches. Unfortunately the side effects of this gorgeous idea: "Let's use the filesystem to manage our files" is enormous. It led to this very tricky option `core.ignorecase` and many other kludges just to avoid developers to re-implement the filesystem layer on Git.

Comment: @nowox: except that, in a sense, it *is* Git's fault: Git should not be depending on the file system. That's what makes cross-platform software so much harder than just staying on a friendly system like Linux. Of course, "not dependent on the file system" gets *extremely* hard when you want to let people see and edit *files*, but at least for branch names, it's not that difficult—the mechanism is already there as no one is supposed to depend on the various `.git/refs/` *files* but rather use `git rev-parse` and `git update-ref`.

Comment: I don't have access to the server (Github) to delete/rename bad branch names, but repeating `git pack-refs --all` and `git fetch -p` a few times until the confusion was resolved worked for me. Until someone creates a new branch with wonky casing, of course...

Answer (score 5):

The answers supplied by [nowox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55052709/100534) and [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) were very helpful, but did not contain the exact solution. The existing references to remote in `.git/config`, and the files in `git/refs/heads` did not contain any versions of `abc` or `def`.

Instead, the problem existed in `.git/refs/remotes/origin`.

My `.git/refs/remotes/origin` directory had references to the lowercased versions of these feature branch folders. Some feature branches were made under `abc` and `def` using the lowercased versions, but they no longer exist on remote. The creator of these feature branches recently switched to using `Abc` and `Def` on remote. I deleted `.git/refs/remotes/origin/abc` and `.git/refs/remotes/origin/def` then executed fresh `git pull -p` commands. New folders, `Abc` and `Def`, were created, and subsequent `pull`s or `fetch`es correctly display `Already up to date.`

Thanks to nowox and torek for getting me on the right track!

Comment: Using `git pack-refs` *should* work, because that will *also* delete `.git/refs/remotes/origin/*` (while leaving the *names* in the packed file, but those names should go away on `git fetch -p`). Edit: ah, I forgot to add `--all` to the recommended command, that might be it.

Answer (score 1):

I met the similar question today. I did the following to solve my problem:

1. rename the 2nd branch to another name
2. rename the 1st branch to 2nd_branch_old_name
3. git push origin 1st_branch_new_name

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to solve my problem:

1. I navigated to the `.git/refs/remotes/origin` folder.
2. I deleted the folder with the buggy branch name.
3. I did `git pull` in the terminal.